# Changing bone roll effects pose

Tags: rigging

I rigged and skinned a model with default bone roll.
Then I changed the bone roll to things like 90, -180, etc. (trying to fix something in unity)

However, I then found that bone roll is effecting the T-pose when it is in pose mode.
[image]

I don't get it. Shouldn't the roll not effect pose mode since it is the "0" rotation?

Comment: The edit bones define the rest pose. Changing a bone roll will roll bones X and Z axis around Y, making it the new identity or zero pose for that pose bone... hence it should effect pose mode.

Comment: But the bone's roll values are only changed in edit mode. If changing roll changes pose mode in "rest" pose, then wouldn't that make it impossible to tweak roll without breaking everything?

Comment: Editing an armatures bones defines the rest pose.  Recommend turning on axis display for bones.   Rolling bones rolls the axes (as described in first comment).  This obviously effects the pose. Hence the answer to _"Changing bone roll effects pose"_ is Yes!